# How to search for a cell containing a certain date?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to search for the cell location of a certain date.

I have a range of dates in dd-mm-yy form and need to be able to find the cell location of a date picked from a drop down menu. I was using a standard Range.Find function which works for searching for Non-dates but when searching for dates it returns error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

I have tried converting the dates to text format through both format cells and a =text function in excel prior to running the program but it still does not work.

I read somewhere about converting the date to match the internal format used by Excel (mm/dd/yy) but this didn't make a difference.

```
'Date to be searched

Set SDate = Sheets("Data").Range("F1")

'find function

Set oRange = Sheets("Planning").Range("A1:A50").Find(What:=Sdate, lookat:=xlWhole)

'Return Address

MsgBox oRange.Address
```

I expect to be able to search for a cell location and be given a cell location, in either A1 form or (1,1). Both will work.

Comment: It should work properly if both your `F1` and lookup ranges are formatted as dates.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but some of my cells had been merged which causes it not to work

Comment: Ahhh merged cells! VBA nightmare ;)

Comment: For the sake of VBA, I vote to banish merged cells!

Comment: If your merged cells are **only vertically** merged, then `Range.Find` also finds in merged cells. But if they are merged horizontally or 2-dimensional, then only `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` finds in them, but `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns` doesn't. If this parameter is omitted, the last used one is in place. (And this behaviour seems to be a bug).

Answer (score 1):

You have merged cells, that's why it returns `Nothing`, try:

```
Sub finddate()

Set Sdate = Sheets("Data").Range("F1")
Set SearchRange = Sheets("Planning").Range("A1:A50")

If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sdate, SearchRange, 0)) Then
    Set oRange = Cells(Application.Match(Sdate, SearchRange, 0), 1)
    MsgBox oRange.Address
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining `.Find` with date values is a tad tricky, as you found out yourself.

Try the following

```
Sub finddate()

'Date to be searched
Set SDate = Sheets("Data").Range("F1")

'find function
Set oRange = Sheets("Planning").Range("A1:A50").Find(What:=DateValue(Sdate), lookin:=xlFormulas)

'Return Address
MsgBox oRange.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I have gotten it to work now!

Comment: @PaulGledhill glad it does! I have changed `DateFormat` to `DateValue`. If this helped you, please don't forget to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
Sub findDate()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of your Worksheet")
Dim dateToFind As Date
dateToFind = sht.Range("F1").Value
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sht.Range("datesRng").Cells 'I am using a named range which contains the dates but you can use A1:A50 instead
    If cell.Value = dateToFind Then
        MsgBox cell.Address
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```